# MariaDB Replication - Replicate only specific tables and views

Tags: database-design, replication, mariadb, migration, schema-migration

Note: A backend developer here with little to no experience in setting up database servers and replication.

**What needs to be done**

Setup DB replication of an existing database with the following constraints:

1. Replicate **only a specific list** of tables/views with different names in the replicated database.
2. Change the name of the tables/views in the replicated database (during the replication process)
3. Setup a user on the replicated DB with further restrictions with which only a set of table/view can be viewed/updated/deleted

**Progress so far**

I have already read the document [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-filters/), however, I did not find anything concrete to help me move forward with all the use-cases I wish to support!

**Use Case**

Show only essential data to the external vendor.

PS: If there are any other approaches other than replication, would be happy to consider and implement that as well.

Comment: this will also need to be kept in sync with original data or 
would it be just a snapshot of original and then both will be used independently ?

Comment: @HarshGundecha It has to be in sync with the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the master host you have to add to the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.cnf`:

```
. . . . .
binlog_do_db = mydatabase
. . . . .
```

Master service should be restarted then.
You can rename the replica's database but you can't rename tables, views and other objects. If you want to avoid collisions between local and replicated objects you have to replicate all the objects into the different database.
On the slave host you have to add to the same section:

```
. . . . .
# DB name mapping (if you need that)
slave.replicate_rewrite_db = mydatabase->mydb
# DB objects filtering - only listed objects will be replicated
slave.replicate_do_table    = mydb.mytable
slave.replicate_do_table    = mydb.myview
. . . . .
```

Slave service should be restarted too.
Next you have to make an initial copy of the data (remotely):

```
mysqldump --host 11.22.33.44 -u username -ppassword --master-data=2 \ 
--quick --hex-blob --add-drop-table --create-options --extended-insert \
--disable-keys --allow-keywords mydatabase mytable myview > mdump.sql
```

Next you have to create an empty target DB on the slave and fill it by dumped data:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword -e 'CREATE DATABASE mydb;'
mysql -u username -ppassword mydb < mdump.sql
```

Then you have to create the slave process on the slave host. `mdump.sql` file contains binlog `filename` and `position` in the header so you can copy and paste them:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword -e 'CHANGE MASTER "slave" TO \
                                 master_host="11.22.33.44",
                                 master_user="ruser",
                                 master_password="rpass",
                                 master_log_file="filename",
                                 master_log_pos="position";'
```

Now you can start the slave and check its state:

```
mysql -p username -ppassword -e 'START SLAVE "slave"; SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS\G'
```

Comment: Have not been able to work with the setup yet. I will keep you posted on how it goes.

Comment: Have managed to setup replication. However table names cannot be modified as you said. Used triggers to write into the table names of choice and then replicate those into the replicas.